# Show that the sequence $(an)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is increasing using induction.

Tags: induction

> The sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is defined recursively as follows:
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{split}
> a_1=&1 \\  a_{n+1}=&\sqrt{a_n+2}
> \end{split}
> \right.
> $$
>   a) Prove the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is increasing (using induction)
>   b) Show that $0 < a_n < 2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (using induction).

For a), I know how to prove it is true for the base case. And I know that next you are meant to assume if its true for that then its true for n+1 however I don't understand how to actually do this second step.

For b) I'm guessing similarly first you'd use the base case to show that it's always greater than 0 since the base case is greater than 0? But after that I'm not sure what you'd do next.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, write formulas in an intelligible way.

Comment: I don't know how to

Comment: @fraser92 - You might find it useful to read this. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: That's great thank you very much.

Comment: (b) looks easier than (a).  If $2 \lt a_k \lt 2$ then $2 \lt a_k+2 \lt 4$ so $\sqrt{2} \lt \sqrt{a_k +2} \lt \sqrt{4}$ and thus    $0 \lt a_{k+1} \lt 2$

Comment: what do you mean by '(an)nEN' ?

Comment: @MattiP. $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a$, you can easily see that the base case is true, that is $a_1 = 1 < a_2 = \sqrt{1+2}$. Assume that $a_n < a_{n+1}$, then $a_n + 2 < a_{n+1} + 2$ then $\sqrt{a_n + 2} < \sqrt{a_{n+1} + 2}$, then $a_{n+1} < a_{n+2}$.

For $b$, you can easily see that the base case is true, that is $0 < a_1 = 1 <2$. Assume $0 < a_n < 2$, then $2 < a_n + 2 < 4$. Root both sides, you get $\sqrt{2} < \sqrt{a_n+2} < 2$, which means that $0 < \sqrt{2} < a_{n+1} < 2$.

Comment: This is a good answer, but a very minor point is that when you "Root both sides", the left side should be $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $1$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan .. indeed it is $\sqrt{2}$